# I need to grep using string "degraded" and I want the output with Health State,Name, and Type. This is in Name Value Pair format

Tags: awk, grep

```
  Name            = Server1.domain.com
  Description     =
  Tenant          =
  Type            = host
  Address         =
  Netmask         =
  OS type         = VMware ESXi
  Ignored address =
  Host group      =
  Health state    = Degraded/Warning (10)
  Health details  = "The host does not have any initiators logged into the storage system. Register one or more initiators on the host to the storage system. This may also require zoning changes on the switches.
```

Formatted for reeadabiliy

[image]

Comment: Is this a single file or some kind of logfile?

Comment: Could you provide what you tried so far, and an expected output ?